# Reading a new line in a string with \n

Tags: java, android, string

When building a string, you can create newlines like so:

```
"This is the first line \n\n And this is the second line";
```

So, when running this portion of code all works well on the Android Emulator:

```
TextView newsTextArea = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.newsTextView);
newsTextArea.setText("Hello \n\n Whats up");
```

However, I have downloaded and parsed JSON from a web service we have created, and I have stored what I want in a variable like so:

```
GlobalSettings globalSettings = new GlobalSettings();
String newsText = globalSettings.getNews();
```

So the variable `newsText` equals a string, which lets say for arguments sake here is `"Hello, this has two lines. \n\n Welcome to the test"`.

When I run the above `TextView` code like this, it outputs it with the `\n\n` as literal characters.

```
newsTextArea.setText(newsText);
```

How can it be done so that the variable `newsText` keeps the formatting?

Comment: `"This is the first line \n\n And this is the second line"`. No. That is aready the third.

Answer (score 0):

im a good guesser..lol well there may be soo many reasons that i think

```
1. newsTextArea.setSingleLine(false);
2. newsTextArea.setMinLines(2); or newsTextArea.setMaxLines(50);//any figure
3. String newsText = globalSettings.getNews().replace("\\\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
4. String newsText = globalSettings.getNews().toString();
```

play with these methods and see if one works for ya or two lol

Comment: Manually replacing this value doesn't seem like good idea. What if original string could contain something like `c:\new folder`? Do you want to replace it to `c:[lineSeparator]ew folder`? (also you probably didn't meant to replace `"\\\n"` but `"\\n"`)

Answer (score 0):

> However, I have downloaded and parsed JSON from a web service we have created ...

There are great chances that your JSON WS returns the literate sequence `\n` as its output. Not the *line-feed character* (`<LF>`) as you expected it.

At this point you probably have two options:

- Fix the web service to return the proper value
- Change your client program to "patch" the faulty data in order to obtain the desired behavior. As of myself, I won't push toward that direction as it will soon become a maintenance nightmare (as soon as legitimate `\` will pop out in your data).

Maybe it is time to post an other question, this time about your JSON web service ?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that wherever that text comes from in the first place, the backslash is getting escaped. For example, it may be coming from a hard-coded constant in your service, entered into a form by a human and then validated, or etc.

Look at your JSON in its raw format before it is parsed. The JSON spec says that a single backslash followed by n means the newline character. If it looks like `["Hello, this has two lines. \n\n Welcome to the test"]` then you should be good, because the JSON parser should interpret the newline characters correctly. However, if it looks like this: `["Hello, this has two lines. \\n\\n Welcome to the test"]`, then the backslash character is being escaped, not the n.

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment - looking at the raw data the \n is coming through as `\r\n\r\n` im guessing this is the problem?